# Trouble with adding rules before deletion of object model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two independent models Budget and Conversion as below.

```
class Budget(models.Model):
    budget = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(to=Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
```

```
class Conversion(models.Model):
    currency = models.ForeignKey(to=Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    rate = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=True, unique=False)
```

I want to add a rule before deletion of object conversion. A conversion should not be delete if there exists a budget who depends from it.

There are many posts regarding deletion of django object but I couldn't find an acceptable solution they all have drawbacks.

What I tried :

- Overriding method `.delete()` and raising a ValidationError -> returns server Error.
- Implementing a `@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Conversion)` and raising a ValidationError -> returns server Error
- Overriding method `.clean()` didn't get called when using Delete from admin.

I would very appreciate a solution that will allow me to prevent user from deleting Conversion objects and without returning a 500 error.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to delete the object without adding rule? I suspect something wrong outside what you are trying to add here

Comment: raising a `ValidationError` is raising an `Exception`, so of course it will return a server error if the error isn't caught. `ValidationError`s only get caught during the clean method of forms, not elsewhere. Why do you raise an error instead of just `pass`/`return` (and not deleting)?

Comment: @WEBBYFOX yes delete work fine without extra rules. And my extra validation works fine it returns my error message but in a Server 500 error. I can attach the rest of code if needed.

Comment: @dirkgroten I could just pass indeed. How can I let know the user that the deletion did not work as the Conversion is used by a budget ?

Comment: Is this in the admin or in a regular view? In a regular view you should just do the check in the view code before deleting. In admin you can disable the delete functionality all together by overriding `has_delete_permission()`. It’s not possible to intervene in the request itself from methods inside the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. You're saying that a `Conversion` object should not delete if there is a `Budget` object that depends on it. But you currently have no relationship between the `Conversion` and `Budget` models in your database. They both reference foreign keys to `Currency`, but that doesn't directly relate them.

If you wanted to somehow link `Conversion` and `Budget`, you could add a foreign key with a `on_delete=models.Protect`, like so:

```
class Budget(models.Model):
    budget = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(to=Currency, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    conversion = models.ForeignKey(to=Conversion, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Now, try pointing a `Budget` to a `Conversion`, then deleting that `Conversion`. Django won't let you do it.

Comment: No that's actually the way I need to design my database I don't want relationship between Budget and Conversion. However  I want to be able to convert a budget based on its date and the currency. I know it's a tradeoff as I won't be able to enforce that on SQL however I try to limit the impact on the admin part.

Comment: Your question states: "I want to add a rule before deletion of object conversion. A conversion should not be delete if there exists a budget who depends from it.". How can a Budget depend on a Conversion if there is no relationship between those two models? Do you mean that a Conversion should not delete if it depends on a Currency that some Budget also depends on?